# get the text of a table with class and data attribute puppeteer and nodejs

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

This is the table

```
<table class="data table additional-attributes">
          <tbody>
                        <tr>
                <th class="col label" scope="row">CODE:</th>
                <td class="col data" data-th="CODE">3170104501</td>
              </tr>
                        <tr>
                <th class="col label" scope="row">CODE OEM:</th>
                <td class="col data" data-th="CODE OEM">3170104501</td>
              </tr>
                        <tr>
                <th class="col label" scope="row">LINE:</th>
                <td class="col data" data-th="LINE">Genuine Parts</td>
              </tr>
                        <tr>
                <th class="col label" scope="row">BRAND:</th>
                <td class="col data" data-th="BRAND">SMA</td>
              </tr>
                    </tbody>
      </table>
```

i need

```
3170104501, 3170104501, Genuine Parts, SMA
```

i tried:

```
let code_example = await(await page.$('.additional-attributes'))
.evaluate(node => node.innerText);
```

Comment: Please, post the entire script

Comment: Seems like a simple `page.$$eval(".additional-attributes td", els => els.map(el => el.textContent))`, no? If you're not selecting the `<td>`s specifically, then you won't get that data. `$eval` is preferred over separate `$` and `evaluate` calls. Also, you haven't told us what the output was from your attempt. It's possible this data is injected dynamically and isn't available, so if you're not seeing anything, consider using `waitForSelector`.

Answer (score 0):

> if use of `querySelectorAll` to get all elements matching the selector:
> create an array, as `titles` is of type NodeList
> Array.from() function can be supplied with a map function directly,
> without a separate call to map.

Scrapping xpath is that from top `table` to bottom `td`

```
"table tbody tr td"
```

This code works

```
titles = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("table tbody tr td"),
        title => title.innerText.trim());
});
```

### Full code

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function getData(url) {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url);

        titles = await page.evaluate(() => {
            return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("table tbody tr td"),
                title => title.innerText.trim());
        });

        await browser.close();
        return Promise.resolve(titles);
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}

getData('http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html')
    .then((titles) => {
        console.log(titles);
    })
```

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        table {
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        td,
        th {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #dddddd;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>HTML Table</h2>

    <table class="data table additional-attributes">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th class="col label" scope="row">CODE:</th>
                <td class="col data" data-th="CODE">3170104501</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="col label" scope="row">CODE OEM:</th>
                <td class="col data" data-th="CODE OEM">3170104501</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="col label" scope="row">LINE:</th>
                <td class="col data" data-th="LINE">Genuine Parts</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="col label" scope="row">BRAND:</th>
                <td class="col data" data-th="BRAND">SMA</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Run html by `GO Live` extension in VS code.
[image]

And run get-data.js, get the result

```
$ node get-data.js
[ '3170104501', '3170104501', 'Genuine Parts', 'SMA' ]
```

[image]